# "IndexError: list index out of range" but it clearly isn't

Tags: python, arduino, raspberry-pi

First of all, I'm new to python, so apologies if this is a silly question (I've got a background in C++).

I'm attempting to split serial data (from arduino) into a list and print specific elements from the list into the console. I won't go into the project details because they aren't important.

The raw serial data looks like:

```
11111110,11111111,11111111

11111110,11111111,11111111

11111110,11111111,11111111
```

The code I'm trying to use is

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import serial, string

output = " "
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 31250, 8, 'N', 1, timeout=1)
while True:
  print "----"
  while output != "":
   output = ser.readline()
   outList = output.strip().split(',')
   print outList[1]
  output = " "
```

I am getting the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "serialtest.py", line 12, in <module>
    print outList[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I have tried replacing `print outList[1]` with `print(outList)`, and I get the expected result of:

```
['11111110', '11111111', '11111111']
['11111110', '11111111', '11111111']
['11111110', '11111111', '11111111']
```

I CAN get `print outList[0]` to work, which prints `11111110`. This suggests maybe it doesn't like `11111111`?

Comment: Is there really a blank line between each line of input?

Comment: It seems it's a single value, you should have a `comma` at the end of index in the list, since there is none when you place your output, there is only 1 value in the list.

Comment: Are you sure you don't see `['']` in between each line when you use `print(outList)`?

Comment: Personally, I think this is a case of learning how to use the python debugger and just stepping though to make sure that every variable is as expected

Comment: The results you show from `print(outList)` don't make sense.  Those are three _separate_ lists, which cannot be the result of `split()`.

Comment: `while output != "":` is testing the variable *after* you try splitting it.

Comment: @Barmar I only see it once when I start the program

Comment: @JohnGordon He's doing `print(outList)` each time through the loop, why shouldn't he get 3 separate lists for 3 lines of input?

Comment: @Barmar oops, my bad.  I thought that was the output from _one_ print statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to test `output` being an empty string *before* you try to split it.

You also need to strip `outLine` before testing it, not just when you split it.

```
while True:
    print "----"
    while True:
        output = ser.readline().strip()
        if output == "":
            break
       outList = output.split(',')
       print outList[1]
```